# Completely disable italic text in GVim

Tags: vim, italic

In GVim I'm using a fixedsys-like font which looks good, but with italic text it breaks (chars partially unreadable, especially the last italic one if the next one is regular).

For this reason (and because I dislike italic text anyway) I'd like to **completely** disable italic text in Vim; without modifying any syntax highlighting related files.

Comment: I'd recommend using a better font. "Consolas" and "Andale Mono" are both fixed-width, and is readable in italic.

Comment: I'm using Fixedsys Excelsior for years and I'd prefer to not switch.

Comment: Not sure about GVim but in regular vim you can say ":se syntax=none"

Comment: Why would I want to disable all syntax highlighting?! I just don't want italics!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether syntax highlighting uses italic text or not is defined by your colorscheme.  Any colorscheme rule can define `term`, `cterm`, and/or `gui` attribute lists, which are described at [:help attr-list](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#attr-list).  You can either clear the relevant colorscheme rules or remove the `italic` attribute from them.

For example, if the following rule is in your colorscheme

```
hi IncSearch gui=italic guifg=#303030 guibg=#cd8b60
```

you would want to simply remove the `gui=italic` bit.  You can also specify not to use any of the attributes from `attr-list` by setting `gui=NONE`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's done in the syntax file: `hi def rstEmphasis term=italic cterm=italic gui=italic`. Is there a way to override it without actually modifying the file?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: you can create your own `~/.vim/after/syntax/rst.vim` and modify/replace the rule there.

Comment: Is there a way to inherit from the original one and simply overwrite the problematic rule?

Comment: You're not overriding the entire file.  You can specify just that one rule in `~/.vim/after/syntax/rst.vim`.  The files in the after directory are just sourced after the system-wide files, so your rules in that file apply on top of what's already been defined.

Answer (score 16):

When using the highly recommended [Solarized theme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), you can configure this using:

```
let g:solarized_italic=0
```

Comment: Incidentally you have to add this to your `~/.vimrc` to get MacVim to pick it up. In case you're using MacVim.

Answer (score 3):

When using the highly recommeded [Dracula theme](https://draculatheme.com/vim), you can configure this by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:dracula_italic = 0
```

**From dracula's documentation**

> Having issues with font styles (italic, bold, underline)?
>
> - Be sure your terminal supports these styles.
> - If running tmux, see tmux section.
> - If all else fails, disable the style by setting `let g:dracula_<style-name> = 0` in your vimrc, where `<style-name>` is one of (`italic`, `bold`, `underline`, `undercurl`,
>     `inverse`)

Comment: Heyo, nice to see a dracula user!